# Show prompt when waiting for non-blocking user input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, select, stdin

I have a non-blocking read from `sys.stdin` using `select` which alternates handlers for my socket and user input:

```
while True:
    input_ready, _, _ = select.select([my_socket, sys.stdin], [], [])
    for sender in input_ready:
        if sender == sys.stdin:
            process_user_input()
        elif sender == my_socket:
            process_socket_reply()
```

in `process_user_input()` I have:

`command = input()`

to get and handle user input.

I want to show a prompt to give a terminal-like view to my users; just like what when using `input('> ')` in a blocking stdin input we can achieve.

But, if I use `input('> ')` in my `process_user_input()`, `>` will be printed after user entered his command (as expected!)

```
some_command
> Invalid command.
```

How can I do that?

**NOTE**: As I have another events happening in my code, there may be some prints in stdout (thus, `print('> ', end='')` will fail). So I want my `>` to be present whenever I'm waiting for inputs, even after some prints in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write output to a terminal, it generally won't *appear* on the terminal *immediately*. Instead, it waits in a buffer somewhere, to be "flushed" to the terminal display at some opportune time. On most systems, that time is when your code writes a newline.

Since you want the `'> '` prompt to appear on the same line as your user's input, you can't write a newline after it to flush the buffer. Instead, you must add the `flush` argument to your `print` function call:

```
print(end='> ', flush=True)
```

If you want the prompt to appear after other output is printed on the screen, you could:

- Add `print(end='> ', flush=True)` to the end of any other code that produces output while your program waits for user input.
- Create your own implementation of Python's standard output stream `sys.stdout`, which would add `print(end='> ', flush=True)` whenever other parts of your program print a newline.
- Use an advanced terminal toolkit such as [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/asking_for_input.html) or [Curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) to always keep your `'> '` prompt at the bottom of the terminal window.

Comment: Sorry for my very late reply. Actually I read your reply on time and used your first solution. But other solutions you proposed are interesting to me and I wish I can make my hands dirty with them later. Thanks.